# Получить указатель на элемент из файла

Tags: файлы, указатели, c++

Ребята, можно ли в с++ получить указатель на элемент из файла?

Конкретнее моя задача состоит в том, чтобы заполнить мультиотображение элементами, взятыми из файла. Так вот, можно ли напрямую прямо и брать, пусть даже посимвольно?

Comment: Ну ещё вопрос, каким это боком относится к C++. А так `man mmap`, если система подчиняется стандартам (posix). 

Хотя насчёт C++ я, возможно, погорячился. Посмотрите http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/iostreams/doc/classes/mapped_file.html

Comment: Указатель указывает на элемент в памяти, так что без загрузки файла в память тем или иным образом — никак.

Answer (score 1):

> задача состоит в том, чтобы заполнить мультиотображение элементами, взятыми из файла.

Александреску в "Современном проектировании на с++" разбирает очень похожую задачу в качестве примера в главе о фабриках объектов. Посмотрите, скорее всего найдете то, что вам нужно.